# Egress via Static IP for HTTP requests from Google Cloud Workflows - NAT/Proxy?

Tags: google-workflows

Is there any way to egress via a static IP for HTTP requests from GCP Workflows?

I know this is possible for Cloud Functions (as per https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip), but can't find any documentation about equivalent functionality in Workflows.

Thanks in advance :-)

Tom

Comment: This is quite new feature of GCP, still in beta, so might be something to be added. Can you share the use case? Maybe this is something worth rising on issue tracker: https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/getting-support#file_bugs_or_feature_requests